# Nothing happens when trying to submit html form variable via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm a beginner javascript user and I'm trying to get this html form to pass to this javascript function and output the name variable but all that happens when I click the button to submit is that the form input clears and it stays on the form not passing to the javascript.

```
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />



    <title>Life Insurance Calculator</title>


        <script type="text/javascript">

        var title = "Welcome to Life Insurance Co..!";
                    //Declaring  variable title             

        document.writeln(title.fontsize(8).fontcolor('red')); 
                   //Printing out the title on the page

        function Name(form){

        var customername = document.getElementByID("name").value;
        document.write(customername);
    }

    </script> 


</head>

 <body>



    <form name = "LifeCalcForm" action="" method="get">
    <p>To get a life insurance quote, please tell us about yourself.</p>
    <p><i>Note:only those under the age of 80 and non-smokers may apply</i></p>
    <p>Enter your name: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>



    <input type="submit" value="Calculate" onClick="Name(this.form)">
        </form>


  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: "submit to javascript" - what do you mean?

Comment: javascript function isn't being called and not outputting the name

Comment: You cannot use `document.write` after the onload has fired.  In you case that happens because the `onclick` almost certainly fires after the onload. On top of that, you will need to `return false` from your `onclick` to prevent the default submit behavior.

Comment: Output where? You can change input to `type=button` if you need just javascript but what you want to do here: `document.write(customername)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
<html>

 <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />



        <title>Life Insurance Calculator</title>


           <script type="text/javascript">

    var title = "Welcome to Life Insurance Co..!";
//    Declaring  variable title

    document.writeln(title.fontsize(8).fontcolor('red'));
//    Printing out the title on the page

    function Name(){
        var customername = document.getElementById("name").value;
        document.write(customername);
    }

</script>


    </head>

     <body>



        <form name = "LifeCalcForm" action="" method="get">
    <p>To get a life insurance quote, please tell us about yourself.</p>
    <p><i>Note:only those under the age of 80 and non-smokers may apply</i></p>
    <p>Enter your name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name" /></p>



    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="Name()">
</form>


      </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks Vicky, this is exactly what I was originally looking for!

Answer (score 1):

When you do `document.write(customername);` after the page has loaded (specifically, after the load event), it will first clear the entire page (including scripts) and write the new content.

Instead do something like:

```
alert(customername);
```

Once you clear the alert (e.g. click "OK"), the form will submit and the page will reload.

Incidentally, since you pass a reference to the function in the call, and the form control has a name, you can use:

```
alert(form.name.value);
```

Be aware that form control names and IDs are used to create properties of the [form object](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-form-element), so having a form control with a name of "name" overwrites the form's own name property (forms also have properties like *submit*, *action*, *elements*, *reset* and so on). So never use a control name that might be the same as a standard form property name, use things like "userName" or such.

Variable names are, by convention, reserved for constructor functions so use lower case for normal functions. Also, functions are do things so it's generally best to use a verb that describes what it does, e.g.

```
function getUserName(form) {
  return form.userName.value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Rob, I was looking for Vicky's solution originally so I accepted her answer but I appreciate your solution and your tips.